# sound quality is bad 20.04.2

Tags: drivers, sound

sound quality is bad, scratchy and a 4-5 second echo on every source.  How do I confirm the sound driver in use and determine the best one?  Ubuntu 20.04.2 low load on CPU

Comment: This happens on *all* outputs or only one? Which one? Please post hardware specifications.

Comment: Check all of your cables, ports, and audio equipment. Audio **quality** issues usually have nothing to do with software.

Comment: I also have had sound issues, installing `pavucontrol` gave me a clearer picture of what device was active where vs. the built in sound settings.

Answer (score 0):

is echo is present on your headphones?

Here is my audio setup -

[audio]
Device=default
DeviceID=0
aec=1
agc=1
bitrate=24000
complexity=10
denoise=1
dereverb=1
signalType=Auto

Try these settings.